# Parallel computation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, ghc

When I run this Haskell snippet it gets only 1 CPU loaded. Both `f` and `g` are non-sense, but shouldn't it load two CPUs when available? Compiled as `ghc -O2 snippet.hs`.

```
f x = 1 + (f $! x)
g x = 5 + (g $! x)

z = a `par` b `seq` a+b
        where
        a = f 3
        b = g 5

main = do
    print z
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to compile with the threaded option, ie `ghc -O2 -threaded snippet.hs`, and then pass the executable the number of cores on the command line as follows for four cores:

```
./snippet +RTS -N4
```

Or you can have the machine choose the number of cores using just `-N`.

See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_for_multicores

Comment: Tried, but I still see only 100% load, not 200% load (have 4 cores in my CPU).

Comment: Wait, I forgot you also need to pass the executable the number of cores, like this: `./snippet +RTS -N4` for four cores.

Comment: Pass only `-N` if you want the program to calculate the cores for you.